# How to run spark scala app in hadoop via ssh?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have scala app object

```
object SparkApp extends App {
  Runner.run(new SparkConf().setAppName("test_scala"))
}

object Runner {
  def run(conf: SparkConf): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val table1 = spark.table("table1")
    val table2 = spark.table("table2")
    val result = table1.join(table2, table1.col("id") === table2.col("id_2"))
    result.write.saveAsTable("test_scala")
  }
}
```

How to run this programm in hadoop? I connected to cluster via ssh and try:

spark-submit --class com.my.org.project.SparkApp --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 500M --executor-memory 500M

But i have: Error: Missing application resource.

Where can be problem?

Comment: please paste the error stack trace and not the message. IT helps people to identify the problem better

Answer (score 0):

The code can run with the `App` trait only when we are testing our logic. Look at the following rewrite of your code and you can build and run it again.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkApp{

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()

    val table1 = spark.table("table1")
    val table2 = spark.table("table2")
    val result = table1.join(table2, table1.col("id") === table2.col("id_2"))
    result.write.saveAsTable("test_scala")
  }
}
```

Updated Spark Submit:

`spark-submit --class com.my.org.project.SparkApp --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 500M --executor-memory 500M spark_application.jar`

Comment: Thanks for reply but it didnt help. Now I have the same error(Error: Missing application resource) with stacktrace that contains arguments of spark-submit function

Comment: Stacktrace: Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]
Options: ...

Comment: Hi petrov. You have not mentioned the location of the JAR file at the end of your spark-submit command